# Count how many different combinations add up to certain value

Tags: sql, sqlite, join, count, inner-join

I have the following table.

```
CREATE TABLE product (
   id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
   name TEXT,
   price INT
);
```

I need to find out the number of 2 product combinations which add up to a total price of 15.

Same combination can only be used once so for example if apple+lemon combination was used lemon+apple can not be used anymore. Also apple+apple would be a valid combination.

Here is the code I have got so far but the results are far off. Any idea for a query which would do that?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM 
    Product p1, Product p2 
WHERE 
    p1.price + p2.price = 10;
```

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax! Easier to write (without errors), easier to read an maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
select count(*) 
from product p1
inner join product p2 on p1.id < p2.id
where p1.price + p2.price = 10;
```

That's pretty much the same query as yours, but with an inequality condition on the product name, so that each tuple is counted only once - which seems to be what you ask for.